# Weighted Moving Average by date R

Tags: r

Below is a script to take a persons stats and do a rolling average by the last 6 days. I would like to have the closest dates to today have more of an impact than later dates.

If it is possible:

- the closest 2 events by date will have a weight of .50 (50%)
- the 2nd closest dates will have a weight of .30 (30%)
- the furthest would have a weight of .20 (20%).

There are two ways of creating the rolling average below `one_df` and `two_df`, I use the first one in my actual script but I added the second in case that would be easier the write in the weight functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Create DataFrame


df<- data.frame(name=c('CAREY.FAKE','CAREY.FAKE','CAREY.FAKE','CAREY.FAKE','CAREY.FAKE','CAREY.FAKE','CAREY.FAKE',
                       'JOHN.SMITH','JOHN.SMITH','JOHN.SMITH','JOHN.SMITH','JOHN.SMITH','JOHN.SMITH','JOHN.SMITH',
                       'JEFF.JOHNSON','JEFF.JOHNSON','JEFF.JOHNSON','JEFF.JOHNSON','JEFF.JOHNSON','JEFF.JOHNSON','JEFF.JOHNSON',
                       'SARA.JOHNSON','SARA.JOHNSON','SARA.JOHNSON','SARA.JOHNSON','SARA.JOHNSON','SARA.JOHNSON','SARA.JOHNSON'
),
GA=c(3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20),
SV=c(3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20),
GF=c(3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20),
SA=c(3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20,3,2,1,1,2,3,20),
date=c("10/20/2016","10/19/2016","10/18/2016","10/17/2016","10/16/2016","10/15/2016","10/14/2016",
       "10/20/2016","10/19/2016","10/18/2016","10/17/2016","10/16/2016","10/15/2016","10/14/2016",
       "10/20/2016","10/19/2016","10/18/2016","10/17/2016","10/16/2016","10/15/2016","10/14/2016",
       "10/20/2016","10/19/2016","10/18/2016","10/17/2016","10/16/2016","10/15/2016","10/14/2016"
),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

one_df <- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(name, mdy(date)) %>% 
  summarise_at(2:5, funs(mean(tail(., 6))))

two_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  top_n(mdy(date), n = 6) %>%
  summarise_at(2:5, mean)
```

**DF:**

```
    name        GA  SV  GF  SA  date
CAREY.FAKE      3   3   3   3   10/20/2016
CAREY.FAKE      2   2   2   2   10/19/2016
CAREY.FAKE      1   1   1   1   10/18/2016
CAREY.FAKE      1   1   1   1   10/17/2016
CAREY.FAKE      2   2   2   2   10/16/2016
CAREY.FAKE      3   3   3   3   10/15/2016
CAREY.FAKE      20  20  20  20  10/14/2016
JOHN.SMITH      3   3   3   3   10/20/2016
JOHN.SMITH      2   2   2   2   10/19/2016
JOHN.SMITH      1   1   1   1   10/18/2016
JOHN.SMITH      1   1   1   1   10/17/2016
JOHN.SMITH      2   2   2   2   10/16/2016
JOHN.SMITH      3   3   3   3   10/15/2016
JOHN.SMITH      20  20  20  20  10/14/2016
JEFF.JOHNSON    3   3   3   3   10/20/2016
JEFF.JOHNSON    2   2   2   2   10/19/2016
JEFF.JOHNSON    1   1   1   1   10/18/2016
JEFF.JOHNSON    1   1   1   1   10/17/2016
JEFF.JOHNSON    2   2   2   2   10/16/2016
JEFF.JOHNSON    3   3   3   3   10/15/2016
JEFF.JOHNSON    20  20  20  20  10/14/2016
SARA.JOHNSON    3   3   3   3   10/20/2016
SARA.JOHNSON    2   2   2   2   10/19/2016
SARA.JOHNSON    1   1   1   1   10/18/2016
SARA.JOHNSON    1   1   1   1   10/17/2016
SARA.JOHNSON    2   2   2   2   10/16/2016
SARA.JOHNSON    3   3   3   3   10/15/2016
SARA.JOHNSON    20  20  20  20  10/14/2016
```

**RESULTS:**

```
name            GA  SV  GF  SA
CAREY.FAKE      2   2   2   2
JEFF.JOHNSON    2   2   2   2
JOHN.SMITH      2   2   2   2
SARA.JOHNSON    2   2   2   2
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**

```
name             GA   SV    GF   SA
CAREY.FAKE      2.05 2.05  2.05 2.05
JEFF.JOHNSON    2.05 2.05  2.05 2.05
JOHN.SMITH      2.05 2.05  2.05 2.05
SARA.JOHNSON    2.05 2.05  2.05 2.05
```

Comment: So your expected outcome is 0.6833? The mean of the weights * values, mean(c(.5, .5, .3, .3, .2, .2) * c(3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3)). Or do you mean a weighted moving average WMA? In which case it would be 2.05 if the weights are c(.5, .5, .3, .3, .2, .2).

Comment: @phiver yes they would be .5,.5,.3,.3,.2,.2

Comment: The weights are not an issue, The expected outcome is. Is it 0.6833 or 2.05 or something else? Also rolling average means a value from the 6th value and further. You might want to create a better expected output.

Comment: 2.05 would be the expected result for this scenario

Answer (score 4):

Getting your outcome can be done with the weighted moving average `WMA` function from the TTR package. The weights are applied to the records records selected for the period length (`n = 6`). The weights should be of the same length as the period.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(name, mdy(date)) %>% 
  mutate_at(2:5, TTR::WMA, n = 6, wts = c(.2, .2, .3, .3, .5, .5))

# A tibble: 28 x 6
# Groups:   name [4]
   name            GA    SV    GF    SA date      
   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
 1 CAREY.FAKE   NA    NA    NA    NA    10/14/2016
 2 CAREY.FAKE   NA    NA    NA    NA    10/15/2016
 3 CAREY.FAKE   NA    NA    NA    NA    10/16/2016
 4 CAREY.FAKE   NA    NA    NA    NA    10/17/2016
 5 CAREY.FAKE   NA    NA    NA    NA    10/18/2016
 6 CAREY.FAKE    3.50  3.50  3.50  3.50 10/19/2016
 7 CAREY.FAKE    2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05 10/20/2016
 8 JEFF.JOHNSON NA    NA    NA    NA    10/14/2016
 9 JEFF.JOHNSON NA    NA    NA    NA    10/15/2016
10 JEFF.JOHNSON NA    NA    NA    NA    10/16/2016
# ... with 18 more rows
```

Or with the NA's filtered out:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(name, mdy(date)) %>% 
  mutate_at(2:5, TTR::WMA, n = 6, wts = c(.2, .2, .3, .3, .5, .5)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(GA))

# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   name [4]
  name            GA    SV    GF    SA date      
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
1 CAREY.FAKE    3.50  3.50  3.50  3.50 10/19/2016
2 CAREY.FAKE    2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05 10/20/2016
3 JEFF.JOHNSON  3.50  3.50  3.50  3.50 10/19/2016
4 JEFF.JOHNSON  2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05 10/20/2016
5 JOHN.SMITH    3.50  3.50  3.50  3.50 10/19/2016
6 JOHN.SMITH    2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05 10/20/2016
7 SARA.JOHNSON  3.50  3.50  3.50  3.50 10/19/2016
8 SARA.JOHNSON  2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05 10/20/2016
```

#### EDIT:

If there are not enough values for the period window, we can create a function and wrap this in purrr's `possible` function to return NA's when the function fails. In the example below I removed 2 records from "CAREY.FAKE" to show the result.

```
my_func <- function(x){
  TTR::WMA(x, n = 6, wts = c(.2, .2, .3, .3, .5, .5))
}

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(name, mdy(date)) %>% 
  mutate_at(2:5, possibly(my_func, otherwise = NA_real_))

# A tibble: 26 x 6
# Groups:   name [4]
   name            GA    SV    GF    SA date      
   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
 1 CAREY.FAKE      NA    NA    NA    NA 10/14/2016
 2 CAREY.FAKE      NA    NA    NA    NA 10/15/2016
 3 CAREY.FAKE      NA    NA    NA    NA 10/16/2016
 4 CAREY.FAKE      NA    NA    NA    NA 10/17/2016
 5 CAREY.FAKE      NA    NA    NA    NA 10/18/2016
 6 JEFF.JOHNSON    NA    NA    NA    NA 10/14/2016
 7 JEFF.JOHNSON    NA    NA    NA    NA 10/15/2016
 8 JEFF.JOHNSON    NA    NA    NA    NA 10/16/2016
 9 JEFF.JOHNSON    NA    NA    NA    NA 10/17/2016
10 JEFF.JOHNSON    NA    NA    NA    NA 10/18/2016
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Comment: What if there are not enough entries for one person to meet the requirement of 6?I should have left one less than 6 for this reason. I get a `Evaluation error: n = 6 is outside valid range: [1,1]`

Comment: I appreciate the time you have spent on this. But it does not answer the question with the result desired. My result df above has the average with a return of just the person and the average throughout the past n days. I would like the same result except adding a weight to it.

Comment: Getting the desired result in your question is just a matter of filtering out the Na's / or selecting the correct rows. But more importantly how do you handle the edge cases? If you don't have at least 6 values per person you need to do something. Which is what the edit shows without any filtering applied. So what is the desired result if you have less than 6 records? And what is the desired result if you have more than 6 records (let's say 8)?

Comment: In the example above there are exactly 6 and we use exactly six. Within the groupyby in example I actually use 25 of that past events for my entire dataset which ranges from some people being in it 80 plus times and other maybe only once or twice. It takes the closest date to the current date and just does an average over as many dates within the 25 game range. I would now just like to apply a weight to the first n games up to a certain point. and if there are people within the dataset with less games just use the weights for as many games as there in. The new df has the person and there stats

Answer (score 4):

I believe the confusion came from the fact you don't really want a moving average but a simple weighted average:

```
weights <- c(.5,.5,.3,.3,.2,.2)
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(desc(date)) %>% # sort dates ...
  slice(1:6) %>%          # ... in order to keep only 6 most recent
  summarise_at(vars(-date,-name),
               ~sum(.*weights)/sum(weights)) # apply weighted average
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#   name            GA    SV    GF    SA
#   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 CAREY.FAKE    2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05
# 2 JEFF.JOHNSON  2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05
# 3 JOHN.SMITH    2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05
# 4 SARA.JOHNSON  2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can also see the weights if you run a part of the code. Essentially it does the same as the answer above.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(distance_to_today = today() - as.Date(date, tryFormats = c("%m/%d/%Y")) )  %>% 
arrange(name, distance_to_today) %>% 
group_by(name) %>%  mutate(rank=rank(distance_to_today)) %>% 
mutate(weight=ifelse(rank<=2,0.5,ifelse(rank<=4,0.3,ifelse(rank<=6,0.2,0)))) %>% 
group_by(name) %>% summarise(GA=sum(GA*weight)/sum(weight), 
SV=sum(SV*weight)/sum(weight), GF=sum(GF*weight)/sum(weight), 
SA=sum(SA*weight)/sum(weight))
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a simple solution, just extending your initial codes :

```
w <- rev(c(.5,.5,.3,.3,.2,.2))

# one_df
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(name, mdy(date)) %>% 
  summarise_at(2:5, funs(weighted.mean(tail(., 6),w)))

## A tibble: 4 x 5
#  name            GA    SV    GF    SA
#  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 CAREY.FAKE    2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05
#2 JEFF.JOHNSON  2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05
#3 JOHN.SMITH    2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05
#4 SARA.JOHNSON  2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05

#two_df
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  top_n(mdy(date), n = 6) %>%
  summarise_at(2:5,function(x) weighted.mean(x,w))
## A tibble: 4 x 5
#  name            GA    SV    GF    SA
#  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 CAREY.FAKE    2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05
#2 JEFF.JOHNSON  2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05
#3 JOHN.SMITH    2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05
#4 SARA.JOHNSON  2.05  2.05  2.05  2.05
```